# D3js code when called twice duplicates the graph instead of refreshing

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, svg, d3.js

Here is my D3js code

```
    function ShowGraph(data)
{

    var w = 600,
                h = 600,
                padding = 36,
                p = 31,
                barwidth = 1;



            var bar_height = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; }), 0] )  // min max of count
                            .range([p, h-p]);

            var bar_xpos = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([1580, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.year; })] )  // min max of year
                            .range([p,w-p]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(bar_xpos)
                        .orient("bottom")
                        .ticks(5);  //Set rough # of ticks

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(bar_height)
                        .orient("left")
                        .ticks(5);

            var svg = d3.select("#D3line").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class","bar")
                .attr("x", function(d) {
                    return bar_xpos(d.year); })
                .attr("y", function(d) { 
                    return bar_height(d.count); })
                .attr("width", barwidth)
                .attr("height", function(d) {return h - bar_height(d.count) - padding; })
                .attr("fill", "steelblue")  
}
```

i run the above code at the click of a button.When i click the button once the graph displays but if click it once again it shows another graph.So now i get 2 graphs.If i click once more i get 3.All i want is to update the existing graph instead of duplicating the graphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you always append a new SVG element (`.append('svg')`):

```
var svg = d3.select("#D3line").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);
```

So instead of using a new SVG element (and thus a new graph), just maintain a link to the first selected graph and override it or select the SVG again:

```
   var svg = d3.select( '#D3line svg' );
   if ( !svg ) {

      svg = d3.select("#D3line").append("svg")
                                      .attr("width", w)
                                      .attr("height", h);
   }
```

Or you clear all content of you element, where the SVG resides:

```
document.querySelector( '#D3line' ).innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove your old svg before appending the new one..

```
 d3.select("#D3line").selectAll("svg").remove();
 var svg = d3.select("#D3line").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);
```