# SVG append issue in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I am working on application in which i am using d3js charts as widgets.
On adding widget, a function is called which creates  and draws the widget(svg element) to that div.

Problem: My problem is that when same widget is added twice, then instead of drawing the d3js chart(svg element) into new div, it gets appended to the previously created div(with previous svg). Also I am facing problem in resizing the charts when the div is resized.

This is the response from ajax:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
var m = [30, 50, 10, 30],
w = 600 - m[1] - m[3],
h = 400 - m[0] - m[2];

var format = d3.format(",.0f");

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, h], .1);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("top").tickSize(-h),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickSize(0);

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
.attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 400")
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")")



  // Parse numbers, and sort by value.
  data.forEach(function(d) { d.value = +d.value; });
  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; });

 // Set the scale domain.
 x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));

  var bar = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
   .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + y(d.name) + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
     .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
     .attr("height", y.rangeBand());

   bar.append("text")
     .attr("class", "value")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("y", y.rangeBand() / 2)
      .attr("dx", 50)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return format(d.value); });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .call(xAxis);

   svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
   </script>
```

i am appending this:

```
 var i = counter;

$('<div class=\"box\" >'+ response +'</div>').appendTo("#data-"+i);
```

Below is the crop image of issue:

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to provide some code.  No one will be able to work out what is wrong without it.

Comment: Oh thanks let me edit the question and provide a code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3js code when called twice duplicates the graph instead of refreshing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544618/d3js-code-when-called-twice-duplicates-the-graph-instead-of-refreshing)

Comment: This is asked frequently. Please search. You are not using the update pattern for d3.

Comment: @In Code Veritas, thanks for your precious time the thing what i am doing is that i have to create a new svg for a new div in ur link it suggest to update or remove previous svg. but in my case i want redraw same at other div.

Comment: I see. Use select() to choose the new div, then. Then append your graph.

Comment: Select is not working as i am using select previously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63111/discussion-between-mayur-and-in-code-veritas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that your main problem is that you are reusing `id` attributes.  You can't have multiple `<div id="chart"></div>` on a single page.  Ids need to be unique.

Each instance of `d3.select("#chart")` will be selecting the same `div`.  It will likely be either the first or last on the page (depending on the browser).

Comment: Thanks @BigBadaboom for ur answer, thats the problem i was facing it. as i am creating a dashboard and this charts are used by user as many times as they want so what can be alternative for it.

Comment: You either need to return chart responses that contain unique ids (ie. generated at run time), or find another approach like generating the div as part of your chart code.